# Why is Xamarin.Forms Entry keyboard popping up and going away automatically on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an Entry element in a Xamarin.Forms app (using XAML layout).  I have an event handler setup to handle the "Completed" Entry event. I have also set up a custom renderer in iOS to automatically "select all" when the entry receives the focus.

What's happening is that the keyboard pops up and immediately goes away and the Completed event is fired. I cannot actually change the text in the Entry.

Why is this happening?

Comment: how are you doing "select all"? It sounds like that makes your entry resign firstresponder, thus prompting the keyboard to disappear

Comment: can you post you renderer code ?